# Replicating MeshLambertMaterial Using ShaderMaterial ignores textures

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, three.js, webgl, shader

I noticed that THREE.js uses shaders internally to create core material "e.g. MeshLambertMaterial", So I decided to copy the lambert shader from Three.js code into a new shader and build on it.

This is the code I got (Copied faithfully from Three.js r66)

```
THREE.MyShader = {

uniforms: THREE.UniformsUtils.merge( [
    THREE.UniformsLib[ "common" ],
    THREE.UniformsLib[ "fog" ],
    THREE.UniformsLib[ "lights" ],
    THREE.UniformsLib[ "shadowmap" ],
    {
        "ambient"  : { type: "c", value: new THREE.Color( 0xffffff ) },
        "emissive" : { type: "c", value: new THREE.Color( 0x000000 ) },
        "wrapRGB"  : { type: "v3", value: new THREE.Vector3( 1, 1, 1 ) }
    }
]),

vertexShader: [

    "#define LAMBERT",

    "varying vec3 vLightFront;",

    "#ifdef DOUBLE_SIDED",

        "varying vec3 vLightBack;",

    "#endif",

    THREE.ShaderChunk[ "map_pars_vertex" ],
    THREE.ShaderChunk[ "lightmap_pars_vertex" ],
    THREE.ShaderChunk[ "envmap_pars_vertex" ],
    THREE.ShaderChunk[ "lights_lambert_pars_vertex" ],
    THREE.ShaderChunk[ "color_pars_vertex" ],
    THREE.ShaderChunk[ "morphtarget_pars_vertex" ],
    THREE.ShaderChunk[ "skinning_pars_vertex" ],
    THREE.ShaderChunk[ "shadowmap_pars_vertex" ],

    "void main() {",

        THREE.ShaderChunk[ "map_vertex" ],
        THREE.ShaderChunk[ "lightmap_vertex" ],
        THREE.ShaderChunk[ "color_vertex" ],

        THREE.ShaderChunk[ "morphnormal_vertex" ],
        THREE.ShaderChunk[ "skinbase_vertex" ],
        THREE.ShaderChunk[ "skinnormal_vertex" ],
        THREE.ShaderChunk[ "defaultnormal_vertex" ],

        THREE.ShaderChunk[ "morphtarget_vertex" ],
        THREE.ShaderChunk[ "skinning_vertex" ],
        THREE.ShaderChunk[ "default_vertex" ],

        THREE.ShaderChunk[ "worldpos_vertex" ],
        THREE.ShaderChunk[ "envmap_vertex" ],
        THREE.ShaderChunk[ "lights_lambert_vertex" ],
        THREE.ShaderChunk[ "shadowmap_vertex" ],

    "}"

].join("\n"),

fragmentShader: [

    "uniform float opacity;",

    "varying vec3 vLightFront;",

    "#ifdef DOUBLE_SIDED",

        "varying vec3 vLightBack;",

    "#endif",

    THREE.ShaderChunk[ "color_pars_fragment" ],
    THREE.ShaderChunk[ "map_pars_fragment" ],
    THREE.ShaderChunk[ "lightmap_pars_fragment" ],
    THREE.ShaderChunk[ "envmap_pars_fragment" ],
    THREE.ShaderChunk[ "fog_pars_fragment" ],
    THREE.ShaderChunk[ "shadowmap_pars_fragment" ],
    THREE.ShaderChunk[ "specularmap_pars_fragment" ],



    "void main() {",

        "gl_FragColor = vec4( vec3 ( 1.0 ), opacity );",

        THREE.ShaderChunk[ "map_fragment" ],
        THREE.ShaderChunk[ "alphatest_fragment" ],
        THREE.ShaderChunk[ "specularmap_fragment" ],

        "#ifdef DOUBLE_SIDED",

            //"float isFront = float( gl_FrontFacing );",
            //"gl_FragColor.xyz *= isFront * vLightFront + ( 1.0 - isFront ) * vLightBack;",

            "if ( gl_FrontFacing )",
                "gl_FragColor.xyz *= vLightFront;",
            "else",
                "gl_FragColor.xyz *= vLightBack;",

        "#else",

            "gl_FragColor.xyz *= vLightFront;",

        "#endif",

        THREE.ShaderChunk[ "lightmap_fragment" ],
        THREE.ShaderChunk[ "color_fragment" ],
        THREE.ShaderChunk[ "envmap_fragment" ],
        THREE.ShaderChunk[ "shadowmap_fragment" ],

        THREE.ShaderChunk[ "linear_to_gamma_fragment" ],

        THREE.ShaderChunk[ "fog_fragment" ],

    "}"

].join("\n")

}
```

and this is the code that I use to setup my uniforms and create the material.

```
var textureUsed = 'rock_1';
var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( texturePath + textureUsed + "/diffuse.png");
texture.wrapS   = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
texture.wrapT   = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
texture.repeat.x = 128;
texture.repeat.y = 128;
var shaderUniforms = THREE.UniformsUtils.clone( THREE.MyShader.uniforms );
shaderUniforms[ "map" ].value = texture;
var material =  new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
                    name: "TerrainShader",
                    uniforms    : shaderUniforms,
                    vertexShader: THREE.MyShader.vertexShader,
                    fragmentShader: THREE.MyShader.fragmentShader,
                    fog:false,
                    lights:true
                });
```

The problem is that when I use these parameters to create a MeshLambertMaterial I get the correct lighting and texture repetitions, when I use it to create ShaderMaterial the lights and shadows seem to be working but the texture map isn't loaded, to fix this I dug through the code and managed to get the map to load by adding this ugly "hack" to my code, right after the material definition

```
material.map = true;
```

Now the texture is loaded and displayed but it looks like the texture coordinates are messed up, instead of repeating, the Shader seems to be ignoring the repeat values I supplied.

Why did I need that hack to get my texture processed and what can I do to get the correct texture repetitions?

Comment: three.js was designed to be easy to use, not easy to modify. This may change in the future... As a start, try adding `material.defines` like so: `var defines = {}; defines[ "USE_MAP" ] = "";`. Specify `defines: defines` in the material constructor, and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, Your modification had the same effect as the "materials.map" hack I used. The texture map is loaded but the repetitions weren't

Comment: `shaderUniforms[ "offsetRepeat" ].value.set( 0, 0, 2, 2 );`

Comment: That solved the issue, but I cannot seem to mark it as solved

Comment: I created an answer for you.

Comment: In case someone is following this, material.map = true; is wrong. Set the map to the texture. https://discourse.threejs.org/t/solved-how-do-we-use-map-uniform-with-custom-shadermaterial/1919

Answer (score 10, accepted):

three.js was designed to be easy to use, not easy to modify. This may change in the future...

You need to set the `material.defines` like so:

```
var defines = {};

defines[ "USE_MAP" ] = "";.
```

Then specify `defines` in the material constructor.

```
var material =  new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
   name: "TerrainShader",
   defines     : defines,
   uniforms    : shaderUniforms,
   vertexShader: THREE.MyShader.vertexShader,
   fragmentShader: THREE.MyShader.fragmentShader,
   fog:false,
   lights:true
});
```

Regarding the texture repetitions, you need to add the repeat to your uniforms:

```
shaderUniforms[ "offsetRepeat" ].value.set( 0, 0, 2, 2 );
```

three.js r.66

Comment: Is this still the preferred method of adding shadow support to a shader material (r92)?

Comment: @Hobbes Yes. ---