# Using/extending the built-in lambert shader in THREE.ShaderMaterial

Tags: three.js

With three.js I've been trying to create a ShaderMaterial that uses the built-in lambert shader, so I can extend the lambert shader and add my own shader code, for instance do some simple waves in the vertex shader, without having to rewrite all the handy lighting code that's already in place.

My code is as follows:

```
var lambertShader = THREE.ShaderLib['lambert'];

lambertShader.uniforms.map = {type:"t", value:this.waterTexture};

 this.seaMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    vertexShader: "#define USE_MAP\n"+lambertShader.vertexShader,
    fragmentShader: "#define USE_MAP\n"+lambertShader.fragmentShader,
    uniforms: lambertShader.uniforms,
    lights: true,
    transparent: true,
    opacity: 0.8,
    depthTest: false,
    depthWrite: false
});
```

First, I copy the default shader program and uniforms from THREE.ShaderLib['lambert'].

Then I set the 'map' uniform to the texture I want to use.

Lastly I create the ShaderMaterial using the lambert shader program.

Problems I am having:

- I have to prefix the vertex and fragment shaders with "#define USE_MAP\n" to let the shader program know it should use the texture map. If I don't add this the texture map isn't used. Adding 'map: true' does not fix this as suggested in a different StackOverflow thread.
- depthTest and depthWrite are disabled but have no effect. When using a normal MeshLambertMaterial this works just fine.
- The texture doesn't repeat correctly like when I use a normal MeshLambertMaterial. (I've set it to repeat 12 times horizontally and 12 times vertically)

I get the feeling there's more #define preprocessor directives that are automatically enabled for MeshLambertMaterials but aren't for ShaderMaterials, or it might be a different problem.

It appears that lighting works correctly though, so at least that's getting sent to the shader.

Is there a way to automatically add the needed preprocessor directives or in any other way fixing the depthTest/depthWrite and texture repeat problems? (because I think that's why the shader doesn't function like it should)

I've looked around in the three.js source and it appears that in [WebGLProgram.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/2d59713328c421c3edfc3feda1b116af13140b94/src/renderers/webgl/WebGLProgram.js), starting from line 127 there is some code that adds the necessary #define statements to a shader program, but I'm not sure why the code isn't called for THREE.ShaderMaterial.

Thanks in advance,
Robin

Comment: See if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21928178/replicating-meshlambertmaterial-using-shadermaterial-ignores-textures/21939336#21939336 helps you.

Comment: Thanks, this solved the issue with the texture not repeating. However the issue with depthTest and depthWrite is still there, do you know if that can be solved by adding something to material.defines or is the solution more complicated?

Comment: Can you show a simple live example to demonstrate that `depth*` works with Lambert, but not with your modified Lambert?

Comment: While creating the JSFiddle I discovered that opacity is another uniform that is not passed by the material to the shaders. When I added opacity as a uniform instead of a material attribute it worked. Thanks a ton!