# Three.JS add color and specular highlights to ShaderMaterial

Tags: three.js

I am using a custom shader which creates a sort of environment map effect by referencing from a texture based on the vector normals and the result is a perfect reflection.

I would now like to be able to add color and specular highlights so that the material is not always 100% reflective. Is there any way to do this without reinventing the wheel and creating a new phong shader from scratch?

If I can set the color or allow lighting, how would I then "mix" it with the texture based output? In Three.js there are lots of mixing methods and it would be nice if I could reuse those too so that I can test each method.

Update:
Found something very similar, just looking for a way to use color, ambient & emissive properties.

Using

```
var phongShader = THREE.ShaderLib.phong;
var uniforms = THREE.UniformsUtils.clone(phongShader.uniforms);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/edgxtnmv/1/

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21928178/replicating-meshlambertmaterial-using-shadermaterial-ignores-textures

Comment: Thank you I did see this question but the two things I am interested in are mixing with my own shader and the specular highlights. The example shows how to add in lots of chunks of code from other shaders but not how to combine them in the end. My shader ends with a gl_FragColor so how will those chunks pick that up. Relating to the specular highlights, the question you refered me to only mentions Lambert shading and not Phong shading so I am not sure which fragments or order I need. I know I have to do something like this but my question is how to merge and what do I need for Phong lighting.

Comment: 1. Get the Lambert shader working in your own demo. 2. Follow the pattern and duplicate the Phong shader in the same way. 3. Then make small changes to the duplicated Phong shader to add in your own logic. You are going to have to study the Phong shader code and understand it.

Comment: I have found this which seems like another method. But I am not sure how to get it to show any color, ambient or emissive. http://jsfiddle.net/Jvf9k/2/

Comment: The fiddle is running a very old version of three.js. The link I posted shows how to set emissive via the uniforms.