# Tileable (repeating) regions of textures?

Tags: three.js

Is it possible to specify rectangular regions of a texture that should repeat across single triangles/quads?

If not, I think I know how I'd write the shader from scratch. But is it possible to add the uniforms, attributes and GLSL code bits to any of the existing three.js materials? (i.e., so I can still use phong, lambert, etc. and apply my edits.)

Answer (score 1):

You want to repeat a *sub-region* of a texture, but three.js allows for repeating the *entire* texture.

There is a work-around, however. You will need to tessellate your geometry, and modify its UVs.

Here is how you can do that with `PlaneGeometry`.

```
// geometry
var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 10, 10, 4, 4 ); // set the pattern repeat here: it is 4

// reset the uvs to be 0 or 1 for each face
var uvs = geometry.faceVertexUvs[ 0 ];
for( i = 0; i < uvs.length; i += 2 ) {
    uvs[ i ][ 0 ].set( 0, 1 ); // first triangle
    uvs[ i ][ 1 ].set( 0, 0 );
    uvs[ i ][ 2 ].set( 1, 1 );
    uvs[ i + 1 ][ 0 ].set( 0, 0 ); // second triangle
    uvs[ i + 1 ][ 1 ].set( 1, 0 );
    uvs[ i + 1 ][ 2 ].set( 1, 1 );
}

// texture
texture.wrapS = texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
texture.offset.set( 0.5, 0.25 ); // set the sub-texture offset here
texture.repeat.set( 0.25, 0.25 ); // set the sub-texture scale here
```

If you do not like that solution, you can extend one of the three.js built-in materials using the approach described in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21928178/replicating-meshlambertmaterial-using-shadermaterial-ignores-textures).

three.js r.69

Comment: Yeah, I want to repeat sub-regions, but don't want to increase model complexity. Ideally specify a list of regions to a shader through a vec4 uniform array and include a regionIndex attribute. Then use some offset/modulus arithmetic in the fragment shader. Will look into using ShaderChunks.