# Three.js: Shadows on custom shader

Tags: three.js

I've searched all over the internet and didn't have much luck so... I was wondering this seemingly simple question: How do you add shadows to a custom shader?

Comment: That will take some work. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21928178/replicating-meshlambertmaterial-using-shadermaterial-ignores-textures

Comment: @WestLangley: Can you tell me how the outgoingLight variable should look like?