# Using a cubemap texture as diffuse source in place of a 2D one

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, three.js, webgl, shader

I'm trying to project massive, 32k-resolution equirectangular maps on spheres.

Since a 32k texture is hardly accessible for older graphics cards supporting 1k-2k sized textures, and scaling a 32k image to 1k loses a tremendous amount of detail, I've resolved to splitting each source map by projecting each into 6 cube faces to make up a cubemap, so that more detail can be displayed on older cards.

However, I'm having trouble actually displaying these cubemapped spheres with three.js. I can set the [`MeshPhongMaterial.envMap`](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Materials/MeshPhongMaterial.envMap) to my cubemap, but of course this makes the sphere mesh reflect the texture instead.

An acceptable result can be produced by using `ShaderMaterial` along with [`ShaderLib['cube']`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderLib.js#L639) to "fake" a skysphere of some sort. But this drops all ability for lighting, normal mapping and all the other handy (and pretty) things possible with `MeshPhongMaterial`.

If at all possible, I'd like to not have to write an entire shader from scratch for such a simple tweak (switching one `texture2D` call to `textureCube`). Is there a way to coerce three.js to read the diffuse term from a cubemap instead of a 2D texture, or a simple way to edit the shader three.js uses internally?

Comment: You will have to create a custom `ShaderMaterial`. Try the approach described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21928178/replicating-meshlambertmaterial-using-shadermaterial-ignores-textures), and update your post if you get stuck.

Comment: did i calculate this right? you would need 4 gigs of memory to store that texture?

Comment: 32k textures are no-no. LOD those textures and tile them. Otherwise, you'll kill the hardware.