# Custom ShaderMaterial map issue

Tags: three.js, shadermaterial

I am trying to create a custom ShaderMaterial reusing the ShaderChunks but seem to have a problem when setting the `map` parameter.

In my custom shader, when I load a texture and set the materials `map` and `uniforms.map.value` value to the texture it does not get the values from the texture in my shader, though it does seem to set the `USE_MAP` definition.

[HERE is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2pha/ah19r4oj/)

In the shader, it turns green if `USE_MAP` is defined, but it should also get the map value.
Am I missing something simple?

Below are the important bits :)

Set up the shader

```
var shaderUniforms = THREE.UniformsUtils.merge([THREE.UniformsLib[ "common" ]]);

var shaderVertex = [
  //THREE.ShaderChunk[ "common" ],
  THREE.ShaderChunk[ "uv_pars_vertex" ],
  "void main() {",
    THREE.ShaderChunk[ "begin_vertex" ],
    THREE.ShaderChunk[ "project_vertex" ],
  "}",
].join("\n");

var shaderFragment = [
  THREE.ShaderChunk[ "common" ],
  THREE.ShaderChunk[ "uv_pars_fragment" ],
  THREE.ShaderChunk[ "map_pars_fragment" ],
  "void main() {",
    "vec4 diffuseColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);",
    "#ifdef USE_MAP",
    '  diffuseColor = vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);',
    '#endif',
    THREE.ShaderChunk[ "map_fragment" ],
    "gl_FragColor = diffuseColor;",
  "}",
].join("\n");
```

Create the material

```
material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
        uniforms: shaderUniforms,
      vertexShader: shaderVertex,
      fragmentShader: shaderFragment
    });
```

Add the texture

```
function loadTexture() {
    var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    loader.load(dataurl, function(texture){
    console.log('texture loaded ok');

    // What to do here to add texture (map) and update ShaderMaterial?

    // Do I have to set needsUpdate on the texture?
    texture.needsUpdate = true;
    // Do I have to set needsUpdate on the material?
    material.needsUpdate = true;

    // Seems I have to set both the uniform map value and the material map value...
    material.uniforms.map.value = texture;
    material.map = texture;

    // But still does not show the texture, though USE_MAP does seem to get defined in the shader (color changes to green).

    // Hmmmm
   });
}
```

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21928178/replicating-meshlambertmaterial-using-shadermaterial-ignores-textures/21939336#21939336).

Comment: Hmm, Adding `defines[ "USE_MAP" ] = ""`, even though an empty string, still makes it defined in the shader so `#ifdef USE_MAP` will be true in the shader even without a texture. I don't think it is a defines issue as just setting `material.map` sets the USE_MAP as can be seen in my original fiddle when clicking the 'load texture' button, it turns green. I think the issue here is something to do with the texture because the shader seems to update, it just doesn't get the texture.