# Enabling Shadow Map on Custom Material Shader

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm looking for a way to create a custom shader which supports shadowmaps. I'm using Three.js version r87.

I have found the following code to create a ShaderMaterial that only renders shadow, however it only works with Three.js r71: https://gist.github.com/ayamflow/93aba91065c2b9750f4f

This is to be used in the open source game Freeciv WebGL at http://github.com/freeciv/freeciv-web

Any help creating a custom shader which supports a shadowmap would be welcome!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21928178/replicating-meshlambertmaterial-using-shadermaterial-ignores-textures. Try replicating `MeshLambertMaterial` using the current three.js shader code. If it doesn't work, show your code and ask a specific question.

Comment: I have created a commit to Freeciv-web here, which combines the updated Three.js Watershader which has shadows, with my Freeciv terrain shader
https://github.com/andreasrosdal/freeciv-web/commit/bd8629c154f618db05f7428347c2295ab08561c5

However, the resulting color is always black. So the shadowmask now works, but it will not work together with my terrain shader. Any help to combine the two shaders?